# understanding docker volume : can i create a volume and assign it to the specific container /service?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I tried creating docker service , docker volume.

my doubt is can i create a volume and assign it to the specific container or service ?

i need some clarification.

can someone give me the clear view on this ?

Comment: We need some clarification too. How do you create the service and the volume? What do you mean by "to the specific container"?

Comment: @Heri : we can create multiple containers right, for example i create 4 containers and i need to create a volume that has to be used only by the specific container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a volume and then assign it to a specific container using bind-mounts or volumes using the appropriate flags. Here's a link to the documentation explaining how to do this - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/